# How can I use JQuery to handle the click on a link having an id that begin with a specific string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-selectors

I am pretty new in JQuery and I have the following problem. So I have a **JSP** page that contains this HTML code:

```
<!-- Bottone relativo ai progetti WIFI: -->
<a title="WIFI" href="javascript: void(0)" id="showWifi_${item.index}">
    <div class="news_box news_box_01"></div>
</a>

<!-- Bottone relativo ai progetti PNSD: -->
<a title="PNSDe" href="javascript: void(0)" id="showPnsd_${item.index}">
    <div class="news_box news_box_02"></div>
</a>
```

As you can see the id of these **a** tag** are something like **id="showWifi_${item.index}"** and **id="showPnsd_${item.index}"**. So these id is creating retriving the **item.index** (a progressive int) that render uniquie id like **showWifi_1**, showWifi_2**, etcetc.

Now I have to use JQuery to handle the situation in which the user click on these links and into this JQuery script I have to retrieve the specific id of the specific clicked link.

So for example if the user click on the **a** tag having id **showWifi_1** this value have to be retrieved.

If I have not this progressive value at the end of the id (the **${item.index}**) I know that I can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Select the 
    $("#showWifi").click(function(){
        //$("p").hide();
        alert("SHOW WIFI");
    });

    $("#showPnsd").click(function(){
        //$("p").show();
        aler("SHOW PNSD");
    });
});
```

The problem is that not I can't use $("#showWifi") and $("#showPnsd") to select my **a** tag because the id are followed by the **${item.index}**.

How can I handle this situation? Can I see something like: when the user click on an **a** tag having an **id** that begin with **showWifi_** or **showPnsd_** perform the script and retrieve the numeric value after the _ character?

Tnx

Comment: $("[id^=startidString]")

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`attribute starts`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) with selector,

```
$("[id^='showWifi_']").click(function(){
```

and

```
$("[id^='showPnsd_']").click(function(){
```

But instead of using an attribute selector, you better set a class to those elements and bind events for it with a class selector. Class selector will be more efficient than an attribute selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard or startsWith selector:

```
$("[id^='showWifi_']")
$("[id^='showPnsd_']")
```

The above selects the `id` starting with `showWifi_` and `showPnsd_`. If you wanna confine your selection to the `<a>` element, then you can use:

```
$("a[id^='showWifi_']")
$("a[id^='showPnsd_']")
```